# How to show null ,empty string,space in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, null, space

Execute the below statements to create database and create table then insert null ,empty string and space and string `x`.

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
\c test;
CREATE TABLE test (
    id numeric(3,0) PRIMARY KEY,
    content varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO test (id, content) VALUES (1, NULL);
INSERT INTO test (id, content) VALUES (2, '');
INSERT INTO test (id, content) VALUES (3, ' ');
INSERT INTO test (id, content) VALUES (4, 'x');
```

All data-- null ,empty string,space shown as same blank when selecting them.

[image]

How can show them properly?

```
test=#  \pset null 'Unknown'
Null display is "Unknown".
test=# select * from test;
 id | content 
----+---------
  1 | Unknown
  2 | 
  3 |  
  4 | x
(4 rows)
```

Remained issue:how to distinct empty string `''` from blank `' '`?Set something to better display empty string `''`  and blank `' '` in psql shell.

Comment: That's an issue with the SQL client. In this case it's the included PostgreSQL command-line shell. Other clients may display data in a different way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would do it in `psql`:

```
test=> \pset null '(null)'
Null display is "(null)".
test=> SELECT id, '"' || content || '"' FROM test;
 id │ ?column? 
════╪══════════
  1 │ (null)
  2 │ ""
  3 │ " "
  4 │ "x"
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Make a little progress.

Comment: SELECT id, '"' || content || '"' as content FROM test;

Comment: Some people might like `\pset null '∅'`, which (in my font) sort of visually stands out a little amongst a table full of regular text values. Consider putting it in your ~/.psqlrc.

Comment: On Linux with Gtk, one can type `Ctrl+Shift+u` followed by `2205` (possibly followed by space) to insert the EMPTY SET Unicde char ∅. On Vim, on insert mode, `Ctrl+v u 2205`, and on Emacs, `Ctrl+x = RET 2205 RET`.

Remember that `\e` on psql launches your editor so a query can be composed from the comfort of your editor.

Answer (score 0):

From here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

```
\pset  null 'NULL'

--Or whatever string you want to represent NULL.

select null;
 ?column? 
----------
 NULL
(1 row)
```

See in [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) under **Files** how you can persist the setting in `.psqlrc`.

AFAIK, there is no way to do this for empty strings and spaces.

Comment: It is null instead of 'NULL' in setting.

Comment: Yeah, I left out the `null` part. Answer corrected.

Comment: How about the remained issue?

Comment: As I said in my answer I know of no way to do that. You just have to figure that anything that does not show up as the `null` string is empty spaces.